# Django:any way to remove this clear field?

Tags: python, django

Is there any way I can remove this model form file field's 'clear' checkbox?.I know that I can define the 'custom' widget for file field but how to address this checkbox in that?[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the widget from the [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) to  [FileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput)

Answer (score 9):

Adding to @schacki's answer.  Here's how to use the simpler `FileInput` widget:

```
# forms.py
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    foofile = forms.FileField(widget=FileInput)
```

The default FileField widget seems to be `ClearableFileInput`.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is quite long, but for anyone still trying to remove the clear checkbox from displaying on the form, just remove `blank=True` from the model.

i.e.

### Models

```py
myimage = models.Image(blank=True, upload_to='my_profile')
```

To

```py
myimage = models.Image(upload_to='my_profile')
```

This is because the `blank=True` is what makes the checkbox appear beside the image-input in forms.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

If you are rendering the ImageField in your template using directly the typical `{{ imagefieldname }}` you can easily format it just substituting it by a copy-paste of the HTML generated by Django after rendering the template.

You can see that "Clear" checkbox in the HTML generated by Django and delete it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of solutions here and elsewhere (removing blank=True, creating a custom modified widget, using FileField, etc...) but none were really satisfactory for my purposes. Here's what I did:

Render the page as normally and inspect it by pressing "F12" in your browser. Look for the element you want to disable and copy the 'id'. In this case it should be something like 'raw_file-clear_id'.

Create a new .css file, 'static/styles.css'. (The 'static' folder should be in the same directory as your 'templates' folder.)

```
#raw_file-clear_id {
    display: none;  /* !important should not be necessary, in my experience */
}

label[for="raw_file-clear_id"]
{
    display: none;
}
```

Add to your django settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<your_project_name>\\', 'static'),  # path to the 'static' folder
]
```

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial06/