# Django Clear Field does not go even after changing widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a `edit_profile` page for the CustomUser I created. I am using the `UserChangeForm`. But I notice that even when I change the widget (as specified here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949945/djangoany-way-to-remove-this-clear-field)) in the Meta class, the clear field is still displayed.

**forms.py**

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_picture = forms.FileInput()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name', 'profile_picture', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
                
        widgets = {
            'profile_picture': forms.FileInput(),
       }
```

**views.py**

```
class EditProfileView(UpdateView):
    model  = User    
    template_name = 'edit_profile.html'
    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name', 'profile_picture')
```

**edit_profile.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
    {% csrf_token %}

     {% for field in form %}
         {{ field|add_class:"form-control-sm"|as_crispy_field }}
     {% endfor %}       

     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

How do I remove the clear field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a form field (`forms.FileField`) and then a widget (`widgets.FileInput`).
The question you linked has the right way, but it seems you copied it wrong.

Your code should be like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_picture = forms.FileField(widget=widgets.FileInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name',
            'profile_picture', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
        )
```